# Trying to make a swipe mechanic in unreal 5

Tags: game-development, swipe, unreal-engine5, swipe-gesture

I'm trying to create a swipe to move mechanic for a prototype mobile game, sort of like Lazy Jump, where the character jumps in the direction you swipe. I was doing good on creating the movement until I realized that the top left of the screen is the origin instead of the center. this messes up my idea a lot because I cant just subtract the end location of the swipe from the start location to get the direction of the launch desired. How can I use the center of the screen in my code to make it work?

at this point my code flings the character in weird directions that I don't want it to go. I have a program that calculates the middle X and Y of the screen but don't know how to implement it yet.

[set swipe start and end](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ftDzO.png)
[checks if swipe is long enough](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kTTnr.png)
[moves the character based on the direction of the swipe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XaLNt.png)
[calculates the size of any screen played on, this variable is not used in any other part of the code yet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/At60d.png)